# Safari is open new window when I play the video

Tags: javascript, css, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I create a video tag in javascript and using the canvas to display the video:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx2d = canvas.getContext('2d');

const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
videoElement.height = canvas.height;
videoElement.width = canvas.width;
videoElement.playsinline = "playsinline";
videoElement.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');

videoElement.src = '.....';
videoElement.autoplay = false;
videoElement.loop = false;
videoElement.muted = true;

videoElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
  (function loop() {
    if (videoElement && !videoElement.paused && !videoElement.ended) {
            ctx2d.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
    }
   })();
});
```

The problem is in my ios device (iphone 11 - safari), when I play the video, ios play the video in new window (fullscreen).

What I need to do to solve that problem? any safari developers here?

This is what I get when I play the video. the fullscreen mode of safari.

[image]

Comment: This is the default behaviour of safari I don't think you can change this.

Comment: as long as you have "playsinline" it should work. i don't know inside a canvas though

Comment: PS: if you got an older iOS try webkit-playsinline

Comment: I add `webkit-playsinline` - still not works.

Comment: I think if I create video tag in js and play the video the ios will display a fullscreen, regardless if I have canvas or not.

Comment: Try `videoElement.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');`